# Can a SEO friendly URL contain a UUID?

Tags: seo, url, url-slug

I have a website with URLs that look like this : http://my-website.com/event/1b3f7e3d-5db2-4dc6-b8f5-e8a0d7e1b572/details/the-title-of-the-event

The long ID (*1b3f7e3d-5...*) being unique and used to identify the event to display.

**Is it bad for SEO to have this long UUID in the URL like this or not ?**

Thanks :)

EDIT: More precise information : the events are created by end users (like an event on Facebook for example). So forcing the title of the event to be unique is not an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An SEO-friendly URL is typically short and contains only a slug and not UUID. So remove the UUID from your URL and add only a slug in it. For example in the URL you provided:

http://my-website.com/event/1b3f7e3d-5db2-4dc6-b8f5-e8a0d7e1b572/details/the-title-of-the-event

Remove the extra details. An SEO-friendly URL should be like this:

https://www.my-website.com/category/post-name

The category in the above URL is called Slug. The **post-name** is called Article Permalink which is also a mandatory part of an SEO-friendly URL. So following the above URL example, your URL can be modified to:

http://my-website.com/event/the-title-of-the-event

Hope I have answered your question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).